# Advection diffusion equation using Crank-Nicolson with total flux and Diriclet BCs

Tags: finite-difference, boundary-conditions, advection-diffusion, crank-nicolson

I am trying to model the 1D advection-diffusion equation:

$${\partial c \over \partial t} = D_c{\partial^2 c \over \partial x^2} -u{\partial c \over \partial x}.$$

With Robin boundary conditions that has a total flux BC at the left boundary (x=0):

$$uc-D_c{\partial c \over \partial x}=uC_f,$$

and a zero-flux BC at the right boundary (x=L):

$${\partial c \over \partial x}=0.$$

Using the Crank-Nicolson method the problem can be discretized and an example of this is presented in this paper https://publications.waset.org/10010828/analysis-of-one-dimensional-advection-diffusion-model-using-finite-difference-method. The spatial domain is discretized in points $i$ from $0-N$ while the temporal domain is discretized with $j$ from $0-M$. Crank-Nicolson in equation form reads

$$PC^{j+1}=QC^j+R.$$

in which $C^{j+1}$ is the (N-1)x(1) matrix containing the unknown values of the current timestep, $C^j$ is the (N-1)x(1) matrix containing the known values of the previous timestep. $R$ is of shape (N+1)x(1) (I assume because it includes points i=0 and i=N) and contains boundary conditions.

I understand the discretization of the non-boundary nodes, but how exactly are the BCs done?
Also, for N nodes, why are the $P$ and $Q$ matrices (N-1)x(N-1)?

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? I have a similar set of PDEs and I am trying to solve in using CN method.